# Minimize a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given

\begin{equation}
X^TAX = 
\left({\begin{array}{cc} x_1 & x_2 \end{array}}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1.5 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{array}\right) 
=
\end{equation}

Find $x_1$ and $x_2$ ratios that will minimize $X^TAX$ subject to $x_1+x_2=1$

Comment: you want an eigenvector for the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you, how would the problem change if we introduced a constraint as i have shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

The quesiton is equivalent to

$$\min 1.5x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + 2x_2^2$$

subject to $x_1+x_2=1$.

Once we perform a substitution, reduce the problem to a one dimensional quadratic optimization problem.

$$\min 1.5x_1^2 + 2x_1(1-x_1) + 2(1-x_1)^2$$

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to write

$$x_1+x_2=1$$ as $${\bf SX}-1=0, \text{ where } {\bf S} = [1,1]$$

This will be solved where $\min_X\{\|{\bf SX}-1\|_2^2\}$

So you can add this term to the minimization:

$${\bf X_o} = \min_X\{{\bf X}^T{\bf AX} + \epsilon\|{\bf SX}-1\|_2^2\}$$

---

**Edit** Sloppily, I forgot to mention that we need parameter $\epsilon$ to say how much more important the fit to equality is than to minimize the first term. $\epsilon=10^3$ seems to work well enough here.

If you are still skeptical, we can derive the solution and type it into Octave:

```
 A = [1.5,1;1,2];
 S = [1,1];
 lhs = A + 1e3*S'*S;
 rhs = [1e3*S'*1];
 Xo = [lhs\rhs]'
```

displays result

```
    0.66578   0.33289
```

pretty close to the real solution [2/3 1/3]. If you don't have Octave and you can't install it, there apparently exists something called [Octave Online](https://octave-online.net/), where you can type it in.

---

This approach is useful in case you have more similar constraints or costs you want to enforce at the same time. You can systematically stuff the linear combinations into such $\bf S$ matrices. Nice if you have like 1000 000 dimensions and 1000 constraints to keep track of.

Comment: -1: This does not solve the original problem, because the minimum $X_o$ does not satisfy $x_1+x_2=1$.

Comment: @Rahul You will just need to weight the scalar product term higher to enforce the equality more harshly, but it will solve it. $\bf SX$ is the scalar product $1\cdot x_1 + 1\cdot x_2$. Just try $\epsilon \|{\bf SX} -1\|_2^2$ for $\epsilon=10^3$

Comment: @Rahul now it does, you can check it for yourself given the link i posted.